# Existence of infimum and supremum in a totally ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

**Problem:** Let $M=\langle A,R\rangle$ be a partially ordered set and $C(M)$ is the set of all totally ordered parts of $M$. Prove that each nonempty totally ordered part of $\langle C(M),\subseteq\rangle$ has infimum and supremum.

Any ideas and suggestions on how to approach this problem would be very much welcome!
As usual thanks in advance!

**Edit**: *All terminology is related to Set theory. I also think that the word 'part' could be replaced by 'subset'.*

Comment: Consider a family $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of subsets of given set : could you find a set contained in each $U_i$, and a set containing each $U_i$ ?

Comment: Suppose the partially ordered set is the rational numbers with the usual order. One of its totally ordered parts is itself (unless "part" means something other than subset, in which case I think that should be explained).  Is it claimed then that that subset has an infimum and a supremum? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy, Yes, 'part' is the exact word used to formulate the problem but I believe it is meant a subset. All terminology is related to Set Theory, so it would be better to think about sets instead of rational numbers in order to generalize the statement in terms of sets.

Comment: @Pece What would the benefits be from finding such sets?

Comment: @e2l3n See Brian M. Scott's answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you take $M = \mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb Q$ is an element of $C(M)$. The claim is that the chains of $C(M)$ have infimum and supremum, it doesn't say anything about the elements of $C(M)$.

Comment: @Pece : It says "Prove that each nonempty totally ordered part of $\langle C(M),\subseteq\rangle$ has infimum and supremum."  If it means what you say, shouldn't it say "Prove that each nonempty set of totally ordered part of $\langle C(M),\subseteq\rangle$ has infimum and supremum."? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy A non empty totally ordered part of a poset $(E,\leq)$ is a non empty set $X \subset E$ such that for all $x,y \in X$, $x \leq y$ or $y\leq x$. Apply it with $E = C(M)$: a non empty totally ordered part of $C(M)$ is a set $X \subseteq C(M)$ such that for any $x,y \in X$, $x \subseteq y$ or $y\subseteq x$. So here, each elements $x$ of $X$ is a element of $C(M)$, that is a totally ordered part of $M$. But you're certainly not trying to show that each element $x$ has a supremum, but rather that $X$ has one.

Comment: ok...  I notice that after writing "non empty" instead of "non-empty" or "nonempty", you went on to do the same thing several more times, so it must be your preferred way of doing it rather than a typo. I've seen others do that recently. Is that how it's taught in schools lately? ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use the term *chain* instead of *totally ordered part*.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a non-empty chain in $\langle C(M),\subseteq\rangle$. We want to show that there is an $S\in C(M)$ such that

- $C\subseteq S$ for each $C\in\mathscr{C}$, and
- if $T\in C(M)$ and $C\subseteq T$ for each $C\in\mathscr{C}$, then $S\subseteq T$.

Whenever the order is $\subseteq$, the natural candidate for the supremum of a collection is the union of that collection, so we try letting $S=\bigcup\mathscr{C}$.

The first thing to check is that $S\in C(M)$: is it true that $S$ is a chain in $\langle A,R\rangle$? Suppose that $a,b\in S$; then there are $C_a,C_b\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $a\in C_a$ and $b\in C_b$. $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle C(M),\subseteq\rangle$, so without loss of generality we may assume that $C_a\subseteq C_b$. But then $a,b\in C_b$, so either $a\mathrel{R}b$ or $b\mathrel{R}a$, and $S$ is indeed a chain in $M$.

I’ll leave it to you to check the two bullet points; the first is obvious, and the second is very nearly so.

There is an equally natural candidate for the infimum of $\mathscr{C}$; I’ll leave its identity in the spoiler-protected block below. Checking that it works is if anything even easier.

> Consider $\bigcap\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: It's a brilliant explanation. Thank you very much! My attempt at proving the two bullet points is 1) Suppose $∃C∈\mathscr{C} : S⊆C$, then $∃c∈C : c∉S$ which is a contradiction to the fact that $S=⋃\mathscr{C}, \mathscr{C}∈C(⟨C(M),⊆⟩)$. 2) Suppose $T⊆S => ∃C'∈⋃\mathscr{C} : T⊆C'$ which is a contradiction to the assumption $(T∈C(M) and C⊆T for each C∈\mathscr{C})$. I'm not quite sure that these observations are sufficiant enough though. Also I took analogous approach for proving the statement that $⋂\mathscr{C}$ is the infimum of $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Actually I don't think that the proof in my previous comment is true. It's not correct to suppose ∃C∈C:S⊆C and neither my assumption on 2) is true. I don't find it trivial to prove the two bullet points.